# django admin get verbose name in template

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm overriding the django `admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html`

I want my checkbox labels to be wrapped around the checkbox, but I can't figure out a way to access the verbose name of the model. Normally I would just add a method to the model but since I'm doing this in the admin and want to do it for every model, everywhere without effort I was wondering if here was an easier way.

This is what I have so far:

```
{% if field.is_checkbox %}
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}" class="vCheckboxLabel">
            {{ field.field }}
            {{ field.give_me_the_verbose_name_for_the_model_plsthx }}
        </label>
        {% if field.field.help_text %}
            <p class="help-block">{{ field.field.help_text|safe }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% else %}
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access verbose name by:

```
field._meta.verbose_name
```

But it works only in view, you haven't _meta in template.

Comment: I'm aware of this method. I was hoping the admin could provide.